# Office 365 REST API /$count filter giving wrong data

Tags: api, outlook, office365, office365api

I'm trying to get count of records for different objects. The response of /$count filtered APIs is inconsistently giving wrong response.
I am referring [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#Count) documentation link for usage instructions.

Request URL: GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/Events/$count

Response: -1

To verify if the above mentioned response is legitimate, I tried to get all events with a skip filter to identify the actual number of records present.
After a certain attempts following request URL gave me final count:

Request URL: GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events/?$skip=159

```
Response:
{ 
"@odata.context": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me/Events",
"value": [
    {
        "Id": "AAMkADMzYzIxNTBjLWUyMWUtNDgzYi04NTEwLTc5YTkzMWI5MmE4MgBGAAAAAABjOnbtK9ZkTIjwInd5bfYcBwDe_ScfFfAUQaKHRwnzV1lBAAAAAAENAADe_ScfFfAUQaKHRwnzV1lBAACs2ojfAAA=",
        "CreatedDateTime": "2016-11-28T11:09:03.8359488Z",
        "LastModifiedDateTime": "2017-02-21T08:04:48.8262751Z"
    }
]
```

}

This implies that after skipping 159 records, I've 160th record present in the authenticated account but $count filtered API doesn't give me a valid response.

I tried testing this scenario with two different accounts where I noticed this anomaly for /message API as well. The HTTP GET call to messages/$count gives me 1563 whereas after trying with skip filter I found the total count to be 1396

I want to know if $count  returns a legitimate response? If yes then explain this anomaly If no then is there any pattern where we should expect response to inconsistent?

Answer (score 1):

To get a count of the number of events, you need to specify start time and end time. Here is what I use:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarview/$count?startDateTime=2017-05-01T00:00:00Z&endDateTime=2017-05-31T23:59:59Z
```

If you don't specify the dates, you will get 400 with the following error message:

```
{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidParameter","message":"This request requires a time window specified by the query string parameters StartDateTime and EndDateTime."}}
```

Comment: The way you mentioned for API of /calendarview, I tried that with /events, it doesn't work  :(, still getting -1 as response.

Comment: Can you please post a link to the api reference you are using? Because I did not see any api call that is close to yours in here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations)

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#Count) is where I found a reference to use count. This example shows message object. In similar way I tested for Calendar and Contacts and a few more objects present in the API documentation. The inconsistency is in case of 'events' where I'm getting response as -1.

Comment: I am getting -1 for the /events/$count api call too. Even in their sandbox ( https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net), -1 is returned. At this point, I think the correct api is with /calendarview/

Comment: I noticed the same behaviour in case of outlook.live.com APIs. Could you please verify for that as well? @AidaNow ??